# What is the general term for $e^x/(1-x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

What id the taylor series expansion for $\frac{e^x}{1-x}$? I know that the series expansion for $e^x$ is the sum of $\frac{x^n}{n!}$ from $0$ to $infty$. But how can I account for the $1- x$ in the denominator. At first, I thought I should write a geometric series with $e^x$ as the a value: The sum of $\frac{x^n}{n! }x^n $. However, this makes no sense.

So how can I do it. Can you please point me in the right direction. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to write the expansion using Taylor series, if you want to break it up, you could use 2 functions $e^x$ and $1/(1-x)$ and multiply the 2 expansions(as pointed out in the comment below this answer) - However, I think it is hard to do that. It may be easier to use the whole function.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @NoChance. Didn't strike me to do this. Yes, I was looking for a way to break it up. Thank you once again.

Comment: You are welcome. The tool listed here may help you to check your answer:https://www.symbolab.com/solver/derivative-calculator/ you need to type Taylor Series followed by your function.

Comment: @user5139637 Actually, there ***is*** "a way to break it up": write down the series for $e^x$ and the series for $\frac1{1-x}$ and multiply them together, as was done in the other two answers. Interesting that you chose to accept the answer that did it the hardest way.

Comment: But I looked at the series (e^x/1-x) on Wolfram Alpha (to check) and the coefficients aren't with a general term of 1/n!

Comment: @user5139637, thank you for pointing out how to break it up. I edited the answer to reflect your idea.

Answer (score 2):

The coefficient of $x^n$ in the Maclaurin series of $e^x/(1-x)$ is
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \dfrac{1}{k!}$$
as you see by doing "long multiplication" of the series for $e^x$ and $1/(1-x)$.  There is no "elementary" closed-form expression for this, though you could write it in terms of the [incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function): 
$$ \dfrac{e \;\Gamma(n+1,1)}{n!}$$

Answer (score 1):

If you know ogfs, multiplying functions is the same as convolution of their coefficients in their generating functions. So multiplying any function by $\dfrac1{1-x}=1+x+x^2+...$ gives you a series with the cumulative sum of coefficients.

Ie your general term $x^n$ will have coefficient $\sum_{k=0}^n\dfrac1{k!}$, though these partial sums do not have easy closed forms.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you write $$\frac{e^x} {1-x}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i$$ So$$e^x=(1-x)\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i-\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^{i+1}$$Now, using Taylor expansion for $e^x$, you then have $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{x^i}{i!}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^i-\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ix^{i+1}$$ Then, for a given degree $n$ $$\frac 1 {n!}=a_n-a_{n-1}$$ gives the recurrence relation $$a_n=a_{n-1}+\frac 1 {n!}$$ with $a_0=1$ and, as Robert Israel answered, this corresponds to $$a_n=\frac{e \,\Gamma (n+1,1)}{n!}$$ where appears the incomplete gamma function.